How to build and use CMake C++ libraries with Premake?
Is there a good and easy way to build CMake projects using Premake and incorporate (link, include, etc.) them?

I haven't used premake, but if it supports execing another process you could just call cmake that way.  I'm not sure what you'd really gain from this approach though since you're going to need to work with cmake one way or another unless somebody has replicated all cmake logic in premake.

90% of your "question" is completely irrelevant. Please make sure your questions are focused on the problem, and avoid irrelevancy. Also, this has nothing to do with c++

"rewriting their scripts" Just build and install your dependencies using their build system (CMake, makefile, autotools, scons, build2, ...) and use your preferred build system for your, including and linking with your dependencies.

@ChrisMM asking how to build c++ libraries seems pretty c++ related to me?

Premake doesn't have native facilities to incorporate CMake projects in their scripts.
You might still run application from premake/Lua if wanted.
I would just build and install 3rd party using their build system
(unless you convert their script to premake's one).
Then regular project usage just have includedirs/libdirs/links possibly defines to be set. so use them as any system library.

Is it possible to execute CMake commands in Premake then?

See how-do-i-run-an-executable-using-lua

So, this question is both yes and no. Can you build CMake projects directly from premake? No. However, that doesn't mean it's not possible using alternative methods.
Here are some possible solutions:

Because premake is just lua, you could use os.execute(), and pass along your cmake build command, at the top of the premake file. Then, later down in the file, just link the newly generated library.
Make a batch script called something like "build.bat", that builds the cmake library, and runs the premake file, which includes the newly generated library file.

